# Is it still possible to develop for gamecube?

Tags: nintendo

I know the Nintendo gamecube is outdated, but it still one of my favorite systems. Is there any way to still develop games for it? What software would I need? What are the programming languages involved? Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you looked at Wii homebrew ? Wii is pretty much a gamecube.

Comment: No.  All the Gamecube devtools were launched into the Sun in 2009 as part of Nintendo's "Gamecube-Shgamecube" campaign at the height of the Wii's popularity. :)  Seriously, though, you can develope for just about any platform, there's relatively little anything "special" about most classic consoles.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, if something has been created and was commonly used, it doesn't fade into oblivion. So searching google wont hurt.

You code using C++, C, GCC objective C with no Java. For the SDK you could go with the DevkitPPC.

> http://wiibrew.org/wiki/DevkitPPC

Comment: is there software for mac osx that will allow gamecube game dev?

Comment: Read the software description carefully, it works on Windows, Mac and Linux. Even if it wouldn't work you could always emulate a supported os on your Mac machine. I gave you a link with everything, but why bother reading 2 paragraphs when you can ask someone to read it for you...

Answer (score 5):

**Possible, yes, but at what cost?**

You'll require special hardware. There's a fairly comprehensive list [found here](http://www.assemblergames.com/forums/showthread.php?29487-Comprehensive-list-of-Gamecube-dev-stuff). And there are [compilers](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/homepage.jsp?code=CW_HOME&tid=vanCODEWARRIOR) that will work for "popular languages" (most likely C++) ([source](http://www.ign.com/articles/2001/07/10/the-ultimate-gamecube-faq)).

There's also a [How To guide](http://www.ehow.com/how_6701621_create-nintendo-gamecube-games.html) that can be found here. The most interesting steps being:

> 4) Find a GameCube software development kit. This kit will allow your
>   team to test the game out on the same specifications that every
>   GameCube runs on. If your game runs inside of the kit, it will run on
>   a GameCube.
>
> 5) Build the programming code in C++, which is used to build programs and
>   games of all kinds because of its powerful backbone. Make sure that
>   the game's world has pre-set rules and that every computer-controlled
>   character has an artificial intelligence that feels realistic.

And of course, the "Things you'll need":

> **Things You'll Need**
>
> - Computer code programmers
> - 3D model creators
> - Audio technicians

This is likely a task that will be fraught with difficulty for very little payoff. Good luck.